# Why the code is put after the return statement, will it get executed?

Tags: javascript, constructor, call

I don't understand why the Function.prototype.call() can be used this way? As far as I know if a function returns the code after that will not get executed. Did I missed something here?

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0)
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product 
                 "' + name + '" with a negative price');
  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price); // if the function returns here why put this.category after this statement?
  this.category = 'food'; // will this ever get executed? 
}
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
```

I understand that both the Product, Food are constructors and we can use call to chain constructors for an object, similar to Java. But why don't put the statement

```
this.category = 'food';
```

before

```
Product.call(this, name, price);
```

Comment: Well, no. If the *current* function returns (or throws), then code located after the `return` statement (or occurring after the exception is raised) will not run. But you're free to call other functions, these won't make your current function return (unless *they* throw and you don't catch the exception).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, thanks for the explanation, so you mean the return of Product.call(this, name, price) won't make function Food(name, price) return right? If that is the case why don't put statement return this; at the end of Food function? As it won't return anything if don't put one

Comment: A constructor function like `Food()` does not have to return anything. It can, but if it doesn't, the object created by the constructor (`this` inside the constructor) is returned automagically.

Comment: also, please please add some curly braces to the IF statement... this hurts my eyes :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know if a function returns the code after that will not get executed.

Yes.

> Did I missed something here?

[`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) works local, and ends only the current function call. The `Food` function does not `return` before setting the `.category` property.

Btw, the `return` in `Product` is unnecessary as constructors don't need to explicitly return.